# Javascript JSON.parse string onclick in-line

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm using jquery to append HTML to an ID; specifically, I am having trouble placing a JSON-formatted string into the onclick parameter of an element.  I intentionally want the JSON to be parsed onClick and am perfectly okay with the JSON living in the DOM for this specific effort.

I think the problem is related to escaping the quotes properly (because a Chrome Inspect Elements debug reveals that each JSON element is being treated as an HTML tag as opposed to a string--see https://ibb.co/eHOgq8 for screenshot of how the DOM is being interpreted)

```
var str = '{"artist":"So and So","title":"Not Relevant"}';

$("#d").append('<ul><li><a onclick="JSON.parse(\'' + str + '\')" title="NA">Link</a></li></ul>')
```

I've tried using numerous escaping mechanism and quote types as well as some native Javascript escaping and gotten no where.  After 2 hours, I have to turn SO for help.   Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What you really want to achieve by putting JSON in onClick?Right now  I is not making any sense .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var str = '{"artist":"So and So","title":"Not Relevant"}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);

$("#d").append('<ul><li><a onclick="alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj))" title="NA">Link</a></li></ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the late but direct answer to the question I have/had.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to assign handlers with inline attributes - that's as bad as `eval`, and as you're experiencing, can lead to confusing issues with escape characters. Instead, attach handlers properly using Javascript instead, for example:

```js
var str = '{"artist":"So and So","title":"Not Relevant"}';
$('#div').append('<ul><li><a title="etc">link</a></li></ul>');
$('div a').on('click', () => console.log(JSON.parse(str)));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!  Maybe I didn't give enough context to address my real problem.  The above will work, but I am in the middle of a loop when I'm writing the updated HTML so each `click` event would need to be against a unique div.  Also, I can get it to log to console in the proper format already but when injected into the DOM, that's where it starts to think the json key/value pairs are actually HTML elements (catching the closing quote of `onClick` too early I think). See https://ibb.co/kv9PtT for real code.  The JSON is trusted (user cannot alter/inject).  Hope you can help!

Comment: That's just an example - if you have multiple `a`s, then of course you'll have to make the selector more specific, such as targeting the last `a` or making a separate variable for the `a` before `append`ing it. If code is relevant to your question, please post it in your question itself (see the How to Ask page)